# How do I fix TemplateDoesNotExist error when using render?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I'm beginning to learn how to use Django. I added a templates folder: `flavo\templates\flavo` with two files in it: `index0.html` and `greet.html`. But I keep getting a `TemplateDoesNotExist`  for all pages.

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index0(request):
    return render(request, "flavo/index0.html")

def greet1(request, name):
    return render(request, "flavo/greet.html", {
        "name": name.capitalize()
    })
```

And my `url.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index0, name="index0"),
    path("<str:name>", views.greet1, name="greet"),
]
```

And in the root folder, I have the following `url.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('flavo/', include("flavo.urls")),
]
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/flavo/

Django Version: 3.2.3
Python Version: 3.9.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\kaij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\flavo\index0.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\kaij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\flavo\index0.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kaij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kaij\Documents\testDjango\flavo\views.py", line 8, in index0
    return render(request, "flavo/index0.html")
  File "C:\Users\kaij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\kaij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\kaij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /flavo/
Exception Value: flavo/index0.html
```

Don't understand why it says the template does not exist, when it's in the folder `flavo\templates\flavo`

My settings.py file is also below:

```
"""
Django settings for testDjango project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = # 'removed'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testDjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testDjango.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: can you also show `settings.py`  file?

Comment: Thanks for checking @coderasha. I added the settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add into my `settings.py` file the name of the application which was `flavo` inside the section of code called `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'flavo',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```